# Projective hypersurface in terms of affine hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field, and let $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \in K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. Denote by $\tilde{f}$ the homogeneous completion $X_0^d f(X_1/X_0,\ldots,X_n/X_0)$, where $d$ is the degree of $f$.

If we consider the projective hypersurface $\tilde{H}_\tilde{f}$, i.e. the zero set of $\tilde{f}$ in $n$-dimensional projective space over $K$, we should be able to write it as a union of affine hypersurfaces, but I'm not sure how to show this. Of course the affine hypersurface $H_f$ corresponds to the points $(1,x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in 
\tilde{H}_
\tilde{f}$, but how do we obtain the points for which $x_0 = 0$, $x_0 = x_1 = 0$, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* We have $\mathbb{P}_K^n= \cup_{i=0}^nU_i$ where $U_i$'s are the *standard* affine open set given by $x_i \neq 0$. Now for any closed subset $V$ of $\mathbb{P}_K^n$, $\{V\cap U_i\}$ is an affine open cover of $V$.

*Edit:* Let $g(X_0,\cdots, X_n)\in K[X_0, \cdots, X_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, and $V:= Z(g)$. Then $V$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Now we want to know what is $V\cap U_i\subseteq U_i \simeq \mathbb{A}^n$. It can happen that $V\cap U_i = \varnothing$, for some $i$. So choose an $i$ such that $V\cap U_i \neq \varnothing$. Then $V\cap U_i$ is an affine hypersurface given by $Z(g_i)$ where $g_i$ is a polynomial in $X_1,\cdots, X_{i-1}, X_{i+1},\cdots, X_n$ obtained by putting $X_i=1$ in the expression of $g$. This procedure is called *dehomogenization* of a homogeneous polynomial. See any standard Algebraic Geometry textbook for it.

Now take a concrete example: $g(X_0,X_1,X_2) =X_0X_1 -X_2^2\in K[X_0,X_1,X_2]$. Then $Z(g)=\cup_{i=0}^2Z(g_i)$ where $g_0(X_1,X_2)=X_1-X_2^2$, $g_1(X_0,X_2)=X_0-X_2^2$, $g_2(X_0,X_1)=X_0X_1-1$ are all affine hypersurfaces.

Comment: It is quite possible that I'm missing the point of your hint, but I don't see how it would give me a way to get the explicit polynomials which give rise to the affine hypersurfaces whose union is the projective one. I must add that I'm not very familiar with algebraic geometry (I had to look up the definition of the Zariski topology again to recall what you meant by "open" and "closed"), so I'm looking for a down-to-earth solution.

Comment: @SWdeVries: I have edited my answer. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!